# Scrolling Div without fixing other elements

Tags: html, css, scroll

https://jsfiddle.net/markustroestler/ubLhygfb/2/

```
<div class="col-10 content" id="content">
         <ul>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>News</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

.content
{
      overflow:auto;
      overflow-x:hidden;
      height:96%;
      width:100%;
    }
```

Hello,
I created a Div which includes plenty of News. I want the Div to scroll but the header and the left-menu to stay fixed. My Div is scrollable but just if the mouse-pointer is inside it. I actually want it to scroll always no matter where the cursor is and i want to have the scroll bar invisible. I tried a few things but could help myself. Is there another way to do this except of styling all the other elements fixed ?

Thanks Markus

Comment: You need the scroll on the `body` of the browser not the `div` for it to scroll no matter where the cursor is located. - You might need to change the structure of how you have build your page. use `position:fixed` for the bits you dont want to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can attach your mouse wheel event to a function and by using that function you can scroll that particular div.

```
document.getElementById("mybody").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
 //Scroll your div
}
```

Hope it will help.